# What would happen if I new a class with a member with customized new operator?

Tags: c++, memory, operator-keyword, new-operator

How is the returned address calculated in libc implementation. What if a member class has self defined  new.

Comment: A member of a class is not constructed with its customized `new` implicitly. The member is just constructed with it's default constructor if you don't construct it explicitly in the constructor of class. The customized `new` for a class is considered if you call explicitly `new` for that class.

Comment: I mean how is the address calculated when new a class(not on stack) with member having own new operator

Comment: The address returned by `std::new` is implementation dependent, platform dependent, and whatever else dependent. There are open source implementations of `std` and `libc` e.g. for `g++` and `clang`. If you are curious, you may have a look into the sources. May be, `std::new` is built upon `malloc()` but that's not required.

Comment: If you overload the `new` for a class it's your overloaded operator which has to do the allocation. It returns whatever you program into to it to return.